# Access contract storage from chaindata

Tags: ethereumjs, state-trie

I am trying to understand how to retrieve the complete storage of a contract based on chaindata (e.g. geth) of a full node.

I have already found how to programmatically access the chaindata (which is basically a levelDB) and the special trie structure:

https://github.com/ethereumjs/merkle-patricia-tree

Is this the way to go to get the contract storage?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Dump the complete storage or lookup single slots?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to dump the "used" storage :) And therefore to access mappings and struct values (of contracts), which are not stored linearly in the storage space (but keccak is involved to identify the memory location)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumping storage is possible

Refer to the functionality of `geth dump`

a) https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/9e5f03b6c487175cc5aa1224e5e12fd573f483a7/core/state/dump.go

b) https://github.com/Arachnid/uscc/tree/master/submissions-2017/doughoyte